# sql query to join 2 tables efficiently

Tags: sql, postgresql

The have the following 2 table2:

```
   Table1(col1 integer, col2)
   1     "This is a string"
   2     "This is another string"
   5     "This is yet another string"
   3      "a"
   4      "b"
   6      "Some other string"

   Table2(col3 integer, col4 integer, col5 integer)
   1    2   5
   3    4   6
```

Now I want to find all the values from Table2 where col4=2. This gives me col3=1 and col5=5. Now I want to join this result with Table1 such that I obtain the string values(col2) corresponding to these integers.

That is, I want the result as: "This is a string", "This is yet another string"

The SQL query which I wrote in postgresql is given below:

```
select d1.col2, d2.col2
from Table1 d1, Table1 d2
where (select col3, col5 from Table2 where col4=0);
```

However, the above query is giving me error. Can someone please help me write an efficient query for the same.

Comment: so do you want your result as one row with two columns or two rows with on column?

Answer (score 2):

You could use an INNER JOIN with two conditions on the ON clause:

```
SELECT Table1.*
FROM
  Table1 INNER JOIN Table2
  ON Table1.col1 = Table2.col3 OR Table1.col1 = Table2.col5
WHERE
  Table2.col4=2
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/e4f4c/1).

Answer (score 0):

try it as a union

```
select col2 from table1 where col1 in (
select col3 from table2 where col4 = 2
union
select col5 from table2 where col4 = 2
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT t2.col2, t3.col2
FROM Table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN Table2 AS t2 ON t1.col1 = t2.col3
INNER JOIN Table2 AS t3 ON t1.col1 = t2.col5
WHERE t1.col4 = 2
```

Comment: Hmm - my answer was already marked down when I posted it.  How is that even possible?

Comment: don't know why did you get downvote, this one looks like only correct answer on the page. You can make it better by creating sqlfiddle.com example and adding link to it. Ah, and you have to change join criteria, it's incorrect now, then you'll get my upvote :)

Comment: @user2310289 well, it depends on how OP wants to get his output, in his question he want to get it as one row with 2 columns

Answer (score 0):

if you want your result as two rows with one column:

```
select t1.col2
from Table2 as t2
    inner join Table1 as t1 on t1.col1 in (t2.col3, t2.col5)
where t2.col4 = 2;

-- output
-- 'This is a string'
-- 'This is yet another string'
```

if you want your result as one row with two columns:

```
select t13.col2, t15.col2
from Table2 as t2
    inner join Table1 as t13 on t13.col1 = t2.col3
    inner join Table1 as t15 on t15.col1 = t2.col5
where t2.col4 = 2

-- output
-- 'This is a string', 'This is yet another string'
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/cd91d/5)</kbd>**